# No TerminalFacade for lanterna - Java

Tags: java, terminal, lanterna

No TerminalFacade for lanterna - Java

Eclipse gets me this error

```
TerminalFacade cannot be resolved
```

For this code

```
Terminal terminal = TerminalFacade.createTerminal(System.in, System.out, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
```

I have looked in the source files and cannot find that class anywhere, I have imported it with jar, and direct source, but neither worked. Not sure why this class doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

Nm they replaced it
If you look in the source src they use this now

```
try {
    Terminal terminal = new DefaultTerminalFactory().createTerminal();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```